# MySql deleting rows of csv file

Tags: mysql

I am trying to upload a csv to a MySql database but the following code is not working. I am entering the query directly into MySql.

```
Create table testing.test (
test VARCHAR(50),
test2 VARCHAR(50),
primary key (test));

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/test.csv' 
             INTO TABLE testing.test
             FIELDS 
                TERMINATED BY ','
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Basically it deletes all rows but the final row of the table. It produces the following message: "7 row(s) affected Records: 8 deleted: 0 Skipped". Any ideas why the rows are being deleted?

Comment: I would assume that your line break encoding does not match that of the csv file.

Comment: yup, it should be `'\n'`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment to the question as answer for others:

I would assume that your line break encoding does not match that of the csv file. That can result in lines getting skipped, since they do not match the described format. Only the last line will get accepted in such scenario, since for that no terminating line break is required.